# Create txt or csv file for analysis in Excel

Tags: android, file, csv, text

I am developing an Android algorithm which uses some parameters and I want to optimize these parameters. Therefore I would like to perform several simulations and write the results into a txt or csv file (say 100 simulations = 100 rows of 3-4 text and number values). The goal is to open the file in Excel for further analysis. What is an easy way to do that and how can I ACCESS and copy the resulting file from the device?

Comment: You should research a little about writing and reading files in Java. You will need OutputStreams and Writers. But in order to get a good path to save the file, try `#getExternalFilesDir()` in your Activity.

Answer (score 0):

I spent some hours for finding the path of the sd Card of my Samsung S5, didn't suceed (even Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), mentioned on many answers to this topic didn't help). Finally I found, that I simply needed to use a virtual device and then Access the data/data Folder in the File Explorer.